# Centering an icon that's origin isn't in the center

Tags: css, centering

I have a Font-Awesome bomb icon that I want to center over an image to cover the hole in the center. However the "center" of the icon is close to where the fuse meets the bomb, to get the bomb to properly cover the hole I need the "center" of the bomb to be in the center of the circle part of the bomb.

http://jsfiddle.net/vhogkv3c/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tF3stnX.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa{
    font-size:300px;
    z-index:99;
    position: relative;
}
img{
    width:400px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background: #fff;
    position:relative;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I tried using fixed negative margins but it didn't seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually solve these problems by using

```
transform: translateX(30px) translateY(-30px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhogkv3c/2/

### Method

It's basically eyeballing until you've hit the sweet spot. You could also use percentages. The way translate works with percentages is it looks at the dimensions of the element you're adding the property to. In this case your element is exactly square (300px by 300px). If we would change the value to:

```
transform: translateX(10%) translateY(-10%);
```

It would do virtually the same as the above code, but will scale accordingly. Try changing the font size in this second jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tgh9a6rw/

In your case the icon's visual center has an offset of exactly 10% on both the x and y axis relative to the technical center. If you're designing the icon yourself you can take this into account and save yourself the eyeballing process with css altogether.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem better than adding margins to me. I'll test it as soon as I get home but it looks like it will work fine. I wonder, how did you get the values to translate by, did you eyeball it or is there a way you knew 30px for sure?

Comment: You're welcome! It's usually just eyeballing, unless you know exactly where the element's 'visual' center is. You could also do this with percentages; I've expanded my original answer to elaborate on this.

Comment: My upvote too. In addition, note that you need the webkit prefix to make it work on safari iOS

Comment: @DasBeasto Did this solve your problem? If it did, could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a `left` and `top` position to the `fa` class:

```
.fa {
   position: relative;
   left: 25px;
   top: -10px;
   z-index: 99;
   font-size: 300px;
 }
```

You probably want to make it more specific though by adding a specific class, because this code changes *every* font awesome icon.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why you made this with flexbox, but you need to adjust the values mannually:

See it working on this edited fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vhogkv3c/1/

I only change first rule:

```
.fa{
    font-size:300px;
    z-index:99;
    position: relative;
    /* these two are new: */
    margin-top:-60px;
    margin-left:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `margin-top` and `margin-left` to your `fa` class

```
fa{
  font-size:300px;
  z-index:99;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -65px;
}
```